# Getting Sitecore 404 for physical files

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

The media library URL  (/sitecore/shell/Applications/Media/MediaShop/default.aspx) is being picked up by the SiteCore handler and redirected to the page-not-found page Sitecore uses (/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx).  The file is a physical file and is actually there.  I've seen things like this happen with items in the Sitecore content tree, but not with physical files.  Any ideas where to look would be appreciated.  Thanks.

**Update:** So, the issue as described above is fixed, but it's clear that there are other problems, seemingly also media related.  This file: /sitecore/shell/applications/media/mediafolder/mediafolder.js is showing the same symptoms I've described above.  They file is there on the server, but Sitecore is redirecting to it's 404 page.

Comment: What are these files, are they something you want integrated into the Sitecore desktop or are they something you want accessible via a www address, i.e. a custom non-Sitcore part of your public webiste?

Comment: They're integrated into the sitecore desktop, living in the /sitecore folder, and are part of the basic Sitecore install.  They're not custom at all.  They work fine in my QA env, just not in production.

Answer (score 2):

Ok...here it is:  Found this line in the web.config:

```
<handler trigger="/media/" handler="sitecore_media.ashx"/>
```

Which should be this:

```
<handler trigger="~/media/" handler="sitecore_media.ashx" />
```

After I made that change, everything worked great.

Comment: Actually, this only partially worked.  Now it's making calls to /sitecore/shell/applications/media/mediafolder/mediafolder.js, and those calls are also returning 404 errors, in the same fashon as described above.

Comment: In that case, I would run a compare between the Sitecore Config between the working/non-working environment and check the differences. Get the config from http://<siteurl>/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx

Comment: Is it possible you may have a processor in the httpRequest pipeline that is intercepting all requests and doing something funky based on the URL?  Something like a 301 Redirects module...?

Comment: We don't have any custom handlers, if that's what you mean.  I'm guessing it's a Sitecore handler that's mis-configured somehow, but I can't seem to pinpoint it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the **physicalFolder** attribute of your **sites** configuration is not set properly.

```
 <site 
    name="helloworld"
    hostName=www.helloworld.com
    virtualFolder="/virtual"
    physicalFolder="/hello" 
    rootPath="/sitecore/content"
    startItem="/Hello Home"
    language="en" 
    database="web" 
    domain="extranet" />
```

Double check if this parameter for the site is set properly. According to the **Sitecore** documentation, the files stored in the physical folder always take precedence over the **Sitecore** Items. Here are some details about the **physicalFolder** part of the **sites** config:

[site Attribute Properties: physicalFolder](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties/physicalFolder.aspx)

If it's not a problem with the sites configuration you may try to put a txt file or an image in the same directory and check whether **Sitecore** serves them properly.

Comment: Actually, it's only happening to a specific batch of folders.  Most of the site is working fine.  For some reason, it's in the media-related folders are causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if this is patronizing, but I'll post it anyway in case it helps.

Have you registered the path to be ignored in the "IgnoreUrlPrefixes" setting? I don't see that anyone has mentioned that, but perhaps that's because it's obvious.

```
<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="/sitecore/shell/Applications/Media/MediaShop/default.aspx" />
```