# Images are not visible in sitecore media library

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I am unable to see any of the images in media library. I am getting 404 when trying to load image through content editor and also by directly browsing to website.

[image: Image is not loaded. Instead getting error]

I am new to sitecore. Please guide me. Sitecore version is 8.1.

Comment: I looks like you have created a custom `extendedmediahandler.ashx` and so the issue lies somewhere there. Without additional details, it will not be possible to help you. Update your questions with details of code and config.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is due to one of the following reasons.

Check the setting 

It should be

You can try to refer this URL. This may help you.

[Getting Sitecore 404 for physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658047/getting-sitecore-404-for-physical-files)